# database migration 05 to 16

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, database-migration

I'm about to do a sql database migration from 2005 to 2016.
How can I check what applications are connecting to the database? So I know what connection strings to update. Is there a script that can do this? I only know how to display the users that are currently connecting to it, but not all applications.

Thank you

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Even if there is one, that will only get active connections from the app. I'd go to each web server / app server and get all of the connection strings from each application folder. Or the hard way would be to turn off the SQL2005 server and see who complains.

Comment: You can check where connections are coming from by periodically polling / storing data in sys.dm_exec_connections / sys.dm_exec_sessions. Make sure you cover a full business cycle because some apps may only connect weekly, monthly, on demand, etc.